# Dynamic getPageWidth() in ViewPager showing images

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

When you add some images in a ViewPager, if the images have different width, it looks weird.
Can i update this width dinamically or something to make it look normal? The first photo is larger in width, and the second one has smaller width. How can i make them fit well in the ViewPager?
Thank you.

I looked at google play app and they made it just fine, does anyone know how?

[image]
[image]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PhotoPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<String> mimages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int mCount;

    public PhotoPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> mimages) {
        super(fm);
        this.mimages = mimages;
        mCount = mimages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        String imageUrl = mimages.get(position);
        return PhotoDetailsFragment.newInstance(imageUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return (0.8f); // this is what i modify
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In principle, there's nothing stopping you from returning a value from `getPageWidth()` that is based on the width of the `ViewPager` and the width of the image for that position. In practice, I do not know if that will give you a decent look-and-feel or not.

Comment: have you encounter this problem before? Can you recommend a different approach to show some remote images in a viewpager(with more then one image on a screen)? I use Volley library and it's nice, but the viewpager thing is a bit confusing now. THank you.

Comment: I do not have any relevant samples for this scenario, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return (0-1]; //(imageWidth/ScreenWidth)
}
```

inside getPageWidth(..){..} you can have a switch case/ if_else conditions to calculate (imageWidth/ScreenWidth) , you can use this value to return as a pagewidth.